# Calculated column won't display when workflow is run

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a calculated column that pulls the text from another site column so I can display just the text. To achieve this I have created a SharePoint 2010 workflow which sets column B with colum A value. I then have a calculated column that will take the text from column B and strip the unnecessary characters and leave just what I want.

I have a workflow which finally takes the two calculated columns and replaces the value inside the Title column for the current item. I have the workflow kick off whenever a new item is created, changed etc. When I create an item it will change the title but the title displays Error;#256 - Error;#256. If I then run the workflow on the item again the correct values are inserted. So I thought the workflow wasn't waiting until the calculated columns were calculated before setting the Title so I modified my workflow as below but I still have this issue.

Laptops is passed onto LaptopString which then LaptopTextOnly is the calculated column that uses LaptopString to get the intended value I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was awhile ago but for anyone else having the issue, I resolved it by having the workflow wait for the calculated column to **not contain** the word 'error.'